# How to activate the 'code overview' widget in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse

I have been researching for some time and can't figure out why this widget is missing in my Eclipse Luna installation.  The screenshot is from a colleague.  The widget is very useful and gives Eclipse a touch of Sublime.

Would be grateful, if someone knew how to activate this in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that it.  Shall I close or remove the question, I wonder.

Comment: Leave the question, it will probably be closed as a duplicate but may help people searching for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called MiniMap which does exactly that:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/620873#.VClCyil_vKk